# #define that would access the member of the structure?

Tags: c

Given a pointer to structure, can I write a `#define` that would access a member of the structure?

```
struct s_block {
 size_t size;
 struct s_block *ptr;
};

#define SIZER(ptr) // will access size member ????
```

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to do so?  Or do you mean: given a pointer to the `ptr` member of the structure, is there a way to write a macro to access the corresponding `size` member?

Comment: No, I actually want macro that would give me result based on ptr to structure, not member of structure. But, I already got the answer. Thanks for clarification .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define SIZER(ptr) (ptr)->size
```

Do note though that you must pass in a pointer to an `s_block` for this to work.

Finally, this should be in any reference manual covering the C programming language. I suggest you pick one up. [K&R](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) is very good, even today.

Comment: I just wanted to note that #define SIZER(p) (p)->size is equivalent.  I want to make sure there is no confusion with similar names.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SIZER(ptr) (ptr)->size
```